# How to get servlet session attribute from taglib JSP page

Tags: jsp, servlets, jetty

Server is embedded jetty. In servlet, I have

```
        session.setAttribute("username", "test user");
```

In the JSP page, I tried

```
<%@ page language="java" session="true" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII" pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:if test="${empty session.getAttribute('username')}">
 <c:out value="session attribute username" />
 <c:out value="" />
</c:if>
```

not working.

If I get session without taglib
<%= session.getAttribute("username") %>
it works. I couldn't find syntax how to get session attribute from taglib.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<c:set var="username" value="test user" scope="session"/>
```

If you need to test then try the following:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.username != null}" > Logout Link </c:if>
```

It should work.

**EDIT**

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.username}" />
```

To get the value.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to set session from a servlet which may not has a jsp page.

Comment: I said if you need :) is the first line, the second line is your solutions to get the value.